# Convert the data of a column of type MapType in a spark data frame to string

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame which has a column of type MapType:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark._sc.parallelize(
        [[{"x": 30.0, "pool": 20.0, "helium": 10.0}, -5],
         [{"x": 40.0, "pool": 30.0, "helium": 20.0}, 5]]
    ),
    [
         "col1", "col2"
    ]
)
```

```
+------------------------------+-----+
|col1                          |col2 |
+------------------------------+-----+
|[x -> 1.0, y -> 2.0, z -> 3.0]| 5.0 |
|[x -> 4.0, y -> 5.0, z -> 6.0]| 5.0 |
+------------------------------+-----+
```

I am having problems writing it to a CSV file. It complains that CSV data source does not support map data type. Is there a way to convert "col1" data into string datatype so that I can proceed with writing to a CSV file? I need the data frame to be converted into something like this:

```
+------------------------------+-----+
|col1                          |col2 |
+------------------------------+-----+
|"x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0"      | 5.0 |
|"x: 4.0, y: 5.0, z: 6.0"      | 5.0 |
+------------------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use spark in built function **`to_json`** to convert your **`MapType`** to a **`string`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df.withColumn("col1", F.to_json("col1")).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------------------+----+
#|col1                                |col2|
#+------------------------------------+----+
#|{"pool":20.0,"x":30.0,"helium":10.0}|-5  |
#|{"pool":30.0,"x":40.0,"helium":20.0}|5   |
#+------------------------------------+----+
```

You could also use **`regexp_replace`** with it:

```
df.withColumn("col1",F.regexp_replace(F.to_json("col1"),'"','')).show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------------+----+
#|col1                          |col2|
#+------------------------------+----+
#|{pool:20.0,x:30.0,helium:10.0}|-5  |
#|{pool:30.0,x:40.0,helium:20.0}|5   |
#+------------------------------+----+
```

You could also **`concat`** with it to get your desired output:

```
df.withColumn("col1", F.concat(F.lit('"'),\
                      F.regexp_replace(F.to_json("col1"),'"','')\
                              ,F.lit('"')))\
                       .show(truncate=False)

#+--------------------------------+----+
#|col1                            |col2|
#+--------------------------------+----+
#|"{pool:20.0,x:30.0,helium:10.0}"|-5  |
#|"{pool:30.0,x:40.0,helium:20.0}"|5   |
#+--------------------------------+----+
```